# Jquery function not working a second time after form submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments

I am submitting a form via a jqery function that's dynamically created with using php and a while loop. The form gets submitted correctly the first time and I generate html and display it using .html(response). I replicate the code so that the function will work again, however it doesn't. When I submit the form a second time (without a page refresh), the form sends me to the action attribute.

Is this a limitation of jquery?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit<? echo"$counter$counter";?>").click(function() {

var action = $("#commentform<? echo "$counter$counter";?>").attr('action');
var form_data = {
comment: $("#comment<? echo "$counter$counter";?>").val(),
type: $("#commenttype<? echo "$counter$counter";?>").val(),
typeid: $("#commenttypeid<? echo "$counter$counter";?>").val(),
counter: $("#commentcounter<? echo "$counter$counter";?>").val(),
is_ajax: 1
};

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: action,
data: form_data,
success: function(response)
{
$("#commentarea<? echo"$counter$counter";?>").html(response);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

My form that's on the same page as the script I am running:

```
<div class="postcommentscomment" style="size:10px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
<form action="php/comment.php" id="commentform<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" method="post" name="comment" target="_self">
<textarea id="comment<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" style="width:162px; height:24px; color:#827e78; font-size:10px;">comment here</textarea>
<div style="float:right; position:relative; margin-top:5px;">
<input id="commenttype<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo $type;?>" />
<input id="commenttypeid<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id;?>" />
<input id="commentcounter<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo "$counter$counter";?>" />
<input id="submit<? echo"$counter$counter";?>" type="button" value="comment"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

My form on the html(response) page via the action attribute

```
<div class="postcommentscomment" style="size:10px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
<form action="php/comment.php" id="commentform<? echo "$counter";?>" method="post" name="comment" target="_self">
<textarea id="comment<? echo "$counter";?>" style="width:162px; height:24px; color:#827e78; font-size:10px;">comment here</textarea>
<div style="float:right; position:relative; margin-top:5px;">
<input id="commenttype<? echo "$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo $type;?>" />
<input id="commenttypeid<? echo "$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id;?>" />
<input id="commentcounter<? echo "$counter";?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo "$counter";?>" />
<input id="submit<? echo"$counter";?>" type="button" value="comment"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

NOTE: The counter php variable is set such that $counter on the html(response) page produces an equivalent result as $counter$counter on the original page.

So, I submit a comment, the comment gets inserted into the database, then a query is run, a form is reproduced and displayed on the original page via html(response). When I then try to submit a new comment I get redirected to the action page. I stopped that by changing "submit" to "button", but that doesn't give me the result I want -- which is to be able to submit the form again.

Not sure if this is a jquery limitation or a problem with my code.

Also, the comments are on a page that has may different posts. So multiple comment forms. If there is a better way to execute a ajax refresh of the comments for a specific post, I am open to changing code.

Comment: All that inline PHP and all those lines without indentation make it pretty hard to help you. I suspect is also make it hard for yourself to spot any possible errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is executed on document ready, if you would insert that code a second time, document ready won't fire again.

You could attach your function to the submit handler of the form...

```
$('.postcommentscomment form').submit(function() {

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    //your ajax call

});
```

You should be able to execute this piece of code every time you insert a form, the serialize function is a more easy option compared to getting all input values by id and saves you from all those silly inline php counter echo's.

Comment: do i need to replace ".postcommentscomment form" with my form id "commentform<? echo "$counter$counter";?>"   ?

Comment: Also, would I have to change my form button type from "button" to "submit"?

Comment: Yes, input type submit for your button.
You could use one selector for all forms, the one in my example selects every form inside an element with class "postcommentscomment", that way you don't need the php generated form id.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I pulled the query out of document.ready. I also changed to function to a standard function not attached to any event. Then I called this function via a on-click event.